# Update xml node values with PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have a table with an xml column that contains millions of xmls.

Im trying to use PostgreSQL to go through them all and update a single xml nodes value. So far I have found that there is no built in way to directly replace an xml node.

Does anyone know of any extensions that does this sort of replacement or is there a way to do it with built-in functions?

The xml similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employee>
      <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
      <LastName>Patil</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Email>tanmaypatil@xyz.com</Email>
      <Address>
           <City>Bangalore</City>
           <State>Karnataka</State>
           <Zip>560212</Zip>
      </Address>
  </Employee>
</Company>
```

And using PostgreSQL I'm trying to update every `<City>` tag's value.

Personally I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
update
    company
set
    company_xml = (
        regexp_replace(
            (company_xml :: text),
            '<City>\w*<\/City>',
            '<City>Delhi<\/City>'
        )
    ) :: xml
where
    id = 1;
```

But does this converting to string and then back to xml cause any unexpected side effects?